# findOne function not working with condition

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I am passing a string to REST API and from the auth service class I am calling the following method from the `user service class`

```
 async abc(email: string): Promise<any> {

const userInDb:Users = await this.usersRepository.findOne({email});
}
```

but it returns an `undefined` object but if I try the following code:

```
const userInDb:Users = await this.usersRepository.findOne(email);
```

it works fine. I want the above code to work.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem. My controller was sending me  `email` in the `JSON` format.